# Update a checkbox on a record to uncheck all other existing records

Tags: apex

How to uncheck primary address checkbox of other records if any new record is inserted or updated in which primary address checkbox is checked? This is what I have so far:

```
trigger addressTrigger on Account_Address__c (after insert,after update)
 {
  Account a=[select id from account where id in(select Account__c from Account_Address__c where id in:trigger.new)];
  list<Account_Address__c> addList=new list<Account_Address__c>([select id from Account_Address__c where Account__c in:Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);
  for(Account_Address__c add:Trigger.new)
   {
     if(add.Is_Primary__c==true)
     {
       a.BillingCity = add.Billing_City__c;
       a.BillingCountry = add.Billing_Country__c;
       a.BillingState = add.Billing_State_Province__c;
       a.BillingStreet = add.Billing_Street__c;
       a.BillingPostalCode = add.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c;
       for(Account_Address__c aa:addList)
        {
         if(aa.Id!=Trigger.newMap.get(add.Id).Id && aa.Is_Primary__c==true)
         {
           aa.Is_Primary__c=false;
         }
        }
     }
   }
 update a;
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors you are facing?

Comment: No errors. But it is not unchecking the primary checkbox for the previous record. So i am having two primary address for a single account

Comment: You a not updating `addList` list?

Comment: Pluto, could you post the code in its entirety. I am trying to do the same thing and have used the snippets below but not getting any action and wondering if Im missing something or I have the code incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are having any errors or not, but you could reduce the number of loops by nominating the id of the primary add record and looping a second time to update the other records. Something like this (this has not been compiled, so it may need further work):

```
Id selectedAddressId;
list<Account_Address__c> updateList=new list<Account_Address__c>()

for(Account_Address__c add:Trigger.new)
{
    if(add.Is_Primary__c==true)
    {
       selectedAddressId = add.Id;
       a.BillingCity = add.Billing_City__c;
       .... etc
    }
}

for(Account_Address__c aa:addList)
{
   if(aa.Id!= selectedAddressId)
   {
      aa.Is_Primary__c=false;
      updateList.add(aa);
   }
}

update updateList;
update a;
```

To prevent an endless loop, you can use static properties on the trigger. Define this global class:

```
global class SingleExecution {

private static boolean blnAlreadyDone = false;

public static boolean hasAlreadyDone() {
    return blnAlreadyDone;
}

public static void setAlreadyDone() {
    blnAlreadyDone = true;
}

public static void forceResetAlreadyDone() {
    blnAlreadyDone = false;
}
```

}

Then add this to the top of your trigger:

```
if (SingleExecution.hasAlreadyDone()) {
  return;
}
SingleExecution.setAlreadyDone();
```

This should fix your issues - use it with the code already provided and it should work fine.

Comment: First exception on row 0 with id a08i000000eKu0qAAC; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, addressTrigger: maximum trigger depth exceeded ................................ I am getting this error     @CaspNZ

Comment: I have updated it. It is running fine but again , not getting the desired results. I am getting multiple primary addresses for a single account.

Comment: You are getting into a trigger loop. I've updated my answer to account for this.

Comment: (Updated now - take a look) - btw, you don't actually need that global class - you can just have a static boolean on the trigger itself if you like. The class is useful if you are going to be checking the boolean on multiple classes.

Comment: @ CaspNZ hey its working fine now. :) Thanks a lot. But Can you give me a little explanation on that global class? I am new to customization.

Comment: What's happening is that the trigger can fire again on the update of the non primary address records, and again and so on. Static variables are maintained throughout the execution context (ie multiple triggers firing) so they can be used to prevent infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
trigger addressTrigger on Account_Address__c (after insert,after update) {

    // Collections to store record values
    Map<Id, Id> accountPrimaryAddressMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();
    List<Account_Address__c> addressesToUpdate = new List<Account_Address__c>();

    // Gather all related Account IDs
    for (Account_Address__c add : Trigger.new) {

        if (add.Account__c != null) {

            accountPrimaryAddressMap.put(add.Account__c, add.Id);
        }
    }

    // Now gather all related Account_Address__c records
    for (Account_Address__c add : [ SELECT
                                        Id,
                                        Account__c,
                                        Account__r.Id,
                                        Account__r.BillingCity,
                                        Account__r.BillingCountry,
                                        Account__r.BillingState,
                                        Account__r.BillingStreet,
                                        Account__r.BillingPostalCode,
                                        Billing_City__c,
                                        Billing_Country__c,
                                        Billing_State_Province__c,
                                        Billing_Street__c,
                                        Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c,
                                        Is_Primary__c
                                    FROM
                                        Account_Address__c
                                    WHERE
                                        Account__c IN : accountPrimaryAddressMap.keySet()   ]) {

        // Check if this Address is the primary address for the Account or not
        if (trigger.newMap.get(add.Id).Is_Primary__c && (!trigger.oldMap.get(add.Id).Is_Primary__c && trigger.oldMap != nul)) {

            // Only update the Account if the address is different
            if (    add.Account__r.BillingCity          != add.Billing_City__c              ||
                    add.Account__r.BillingCountry       != add.Billing_Country__c           ||
                    add.Account__r.BillingState         != add.Billing_State_Province__c    ||
                    add.Account__r.BillingStreet        != add.Billing_Street__c            ||
                    add.Account__r.BillingPostalCode    != add.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c   ) {

                Account a = new Account(
                    a.Id                    = add.Account__r.Id,
                    a.BillingCity           = add.Billing_City__c,
                    a.BillingCountry        = add.Billing_Country__c,
                    a.BillingState          = add.Billing_State_Province__c,
                    a.BillingStreet         = add.Billing_Street__c,
                    a.BillingPostalCode     = add.Billing_Zip_Postal_Code__c
                );

                accountsToUpdate.put(a.Id, a);
            }

        } else {

            // If the Is_Primary__c flag is set to true, correct that now
            add.Is_Primary__c = false;
            addressesToUpdate.add(add);
        }
    }

    // Now update the records
    if (!accountsToUpdate.values().isEmpty()) {

        update accountsToUpdate.values();
    }

    if (!addressesToUpdate.isEmpty()) {

        update addressesToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ DavinC   An error is coming on this statement                                                      if (trigger.newMap.get(add.Id).Is_Primary__c && (!trigger.oldMap.get(add.Id).Is_Primary__c && trigger.newMap != null))                                                       System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.addressTrigger: line 35, column 1

Comment: @pluto Sorry that was a typo on my part now, have updated the code.